# Change width proportions of two blocks with a slider

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, flexbox

I'm trying to design a component in which you could change the width proportions of two blocks by moving a slider left and right:
[image]

[codpen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jRMryb) and demo:

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.block {
  height: 200px;
  width: -webkit-calc(50% - 5px);
  width: -moz-calc(50% - 5px);
  width: calc(50% - 5px);
}

.block-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.block-2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.slider {
  line-height: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #dee2e6;
  border: none;
  cursor: e-resize;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="block block-1">
      Block 1
    </div>
    <div class="slider">
      S<br>l<br>i<br>d<br>e<br>r
    </div>
    <div class="block block-2">
      Block 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using [`draggable-vue-directive`](https://github.com/IsraelZablianov/draggable-vue-directive) and change the width of blocks based on slider position.

However, it didn't work really well, since `draggable-vue-directive` set the slider to `position:fixed` which in turn messed up the block alignment.

How can I make the `.slider` block horizontally draggable without setting `position:fixed`?

How to correctly resize `Block1` and `Block2` when slider moves?

*Note: I'm not using `jQuery`*

Comment: There are lots of ways to make a slider. What are you trying to accomplish with it? Your current implementation will simply reflow the content in each area as they become wider/narrower. Is that the goal?

Comment: @BryceHowitson yeah, basically if you slide the slider `div` to the right, then `Block 1` should be wider and `Block 2` should be narrower

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can adjust your *flexbox* along with [**`resize`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize) - the ***downside*** is that the *slider* its not very customizeable:

- add `resize: horizontal` to one of the flex items
- add `flex: 1` to the other flex item (so that *this* flex item will adjust automatically in response to the changing width of the other flex item as it is resized)

See demo below:

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.block {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50%; /* 50% would suffice*/
}

.block-1 {
  background-color: red;
  resize: horizontal; /* resize horizontal */
  overflow: hidden; /* resize works for overflow other than visible */
}

.block-2 {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1; /* adjust automatically */
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="block block-1">
      Block 1
    </div>
    <div class="block block-2">
      Block 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

So we'll use *vanilla JS* instead of the *resize* solution above:

- use a `mousedown` listener that *registers* a `mousemove` listener that updates the `block-1` width (and *reset* the `mouseup` event)
- also consider `min-width: 0` to *override* `min-width: auto` of the `block-2` element

See demo below:

```js
let block = document.querySelector(".block-1"),
  slider = document.querySelector(".slider");

slider.onmousedown = function dragMouseDown(e) {
  let dragX = e.clientX;
  document.onmousemove = function onMouseMove(e) {
    block.style.width = block.offsetWidth + e.clientX - dragX + "px";
    dragX = e.clientX;
  }
  // remove mouse-move listener on mouse-up
  document.onmouseup = () => document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
}
```

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.block {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50%; /* 50% would suffice*/
}

.block-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.block-2 {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1; /* adjust automatically */
  min-width: 0; /* allow flexing beyond auto width */
  overflow: hidden; /* hide overflow on small width */
}

.slider {
  line-height: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #dee2e6;
  border: none;
  cursor: col-resize;
  user-select: none; /* disable selection */
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="block block-1">
      Block 1
    </div>
    <div class="slider">
      S<br>l<br>i<br>d<br>e<br>r
    </div>
    <div class="block block-2">
      Block 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Solution

You can adapt the above into Vue easily *without* using any custom Vue plugins for this - the changes are:

- `@mousedown` listener on `slider` that *triggers* the slider
- use of [**`refs`**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) to update the width of `block-1`

See demo below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    block1W: '50%'
  },
  methods: {
    drag: function(e) {
      let dragX = e.clientX;
      let block = this.$refs.block1;
      document.onmousemove = function onMouseMove(e) {
        block.style.width = block.offsetWidth + e.clientX - dragX + "px";
        dragX = e.clientX;
      }
      // remove mouse-move listener on mouse-up
      document.onmouseup = () => document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.block {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50%; /* 50% would suffice*/
}

.block-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.block-2 {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1; /* adjust automatically */
  min-width: 0; /* allow flexing beyond auto width */
  overflow: hidden; /* hide overflow on small width */
}

.slider {
  line-height: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #dee2e6;
  border: none;
  cursor: col-resize;
  user-select: none; /* disable selection */
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="block block-1" ref="block1" :style="{'width': block1W}">
      Block 1
    </div>
    <div class="slider" @mousedown="drag">
      S<br>l<br>i<br>d<br>e<br>r
    </div>
    <div class="block block-2">
      Block 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer indeed. It's also quite nice that the solution is first based on "vanilla" JS and then "migrated" to a Vue-targeted solution. Personally, I would just use `addEventListener` instead of using the "on..." properties in JS, but that's not important here for the general functionality. Good work. Thank you very much.