# Creating a container that has 3 divs as columns which has horizontal draggable inner borders

Tags: javascript, html, css

so the problem is; I have 1 container that has 3 columns within it which start off with all even widths, but the borders on the middle column need to be able to be "dragged" / resized.

The ideal solution would be with CSS and HTML only.

The way I'm going about it currently is using resize: horizontal; & overflow-y: auto; Then set all initial widths.

HTML (simplified) - feel free to add more classes

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    height: auto;
    width: 100vw;
    background: #fff;

    > div{
      overflow-y: auto;

      &:first-child {
        width: 500px;
        resize: horizontal;  
      }

      &:nth-child(2) {
        width: 33%;
        resize: horizontal;
        overflow: auto;
      }

      &:last-child {
        width: 500px;
        flex: 1;
      }
    }
}
```

Ideal solution: Whole column border is draggable, but we can't use a mouse down/mouse move event handler as it's a too intensive process. Also Javascript is currently off the table - although a solution with pure JS would be a fun learning experience.

Current solution: Bottom right corner is resizable in a horizontal direction only, but you can "overdrag" and send the columns into a weird width that you have to invisibly drag back again. Just not a very smooth experience.

Is there a solution out there that does it better than what I currently have?

Comment: You can't create a draggable element without JavaScript.

Comment: you can adopt the 2-item flexbox examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55559527/change-width-proportions-of-two-blocks-with-a-slider/55561510#55561510) for horizontal direction and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55565001/how-do-you-allow-a-user-to-manually-resize-a-div-element-vertically/55565128#55565128) for slider in vertical direction...

Comment: What you are describing requires JS