# CSS Grid resizable cell

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In the following layout, I want to make the green color section to be re sizable. When it's resized, cell 8 should take the whatever the space left without affecting any other cells in other rows.

```css
.App {
  display: grid;
  
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr 200px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 200px 30px;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.App > div {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.nav {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div class="nav">7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
</div>
```

Size change will be done by the user. But to demonstrate, consider changing `width` of the `.nav` element to `100px`. After size of `.nav` is changed, 8 cell should take the remaining space and grow.

```
.nav {
    background: green;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Is this kind of a behavior is possible using `CSS Grid`?

Comment: No...this is something flexbox is designed to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change `nav` width and expect that it only affect the element next to it - it affect the whole first column. You can try resizing the `nav` in the demo below (using `grid-template-columns: auto 1fr 200px`) along with sufficient `min-width` and `max-width`:

```css
.App {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr 200px; /* changed */
  grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 200px 30px;
}

.App > div {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.nav {
  background: green;
  width: 100px; /* default width */
  max-width: calc(100vw - 260px); /* do go beyond the third column */
  min-width: 25px; /* min width of nav */
  resize: horizontal; /* resize the div */
  overflow: hidden; /* resize works if overflow not visible */
}
```

```html
<div class="App"><div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div class="nav">7</div><div>8</div><div>9</div><div>10</div><div>11</div><div>12</div></div>
```

---

That's as far as you can have with the current markup. If you can change your html by wrapping the `8` and `7` into a 2-column *grid item* and make if a flexbox, you can have the desired effect - see demo below:

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.App {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 200px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 200px 30px;
}

.App > div {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.nav {
  grid-column: span 2;
  display: flex;
}
.nav > div:first-child {
  background: green;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
}
.nav > div:last-child {
  flex: 1;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div class="nav">
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
  </div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
</div>
```

You can read more about flexboxes with a resizable slider in these posts:

- [Change width proportions of two blocks with a slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55559527/change-width-proportions-of-two-blocks-with-a-slider/55561510#55561510)
- [How do you allow a user to manually resize a <div> element vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55565001/how-do-you-allow-a-user-to-manually-resize-a-div-element-vertically/55565128#55565128)

Comment: First one is not the solution since i don't want width of other row cells to be changed except 7th and 8th cells. Flex box solution works for me.